# VSCode Powershell Syntax Highlightning Error/Bug

Tags: powershell, themes, visual-studio-code

i got some problems with syntax-highlightning in vscode, specific: powershell.

[vscode-powershell-syntaxerror-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwwYF.png)

Themes / extensions:

- FlatUI Theme
- Custom CSS Loader
- Powershell Language
- Powershell Pro Tools
- Powershell Console
- Material Icon Theme

How can i fix this?
It's not preventing me from coding but it's annoying as hell.
It's only in Powershell, not c++/c#, vb.net, jscript or anything else...

VSCode is up-to-date

Comment: Did you at a minimum , resetting VSCode to the color defaults and or use a different theme, disable all add-ins except PowerShell? Eliminate all that is impossible, all that is left is possible.

Comment: i did that, it was the first thing i did: complete reinstalling vscode with no extensions/themes.